# How to perform operations on cvxopt-matrices a la numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, cvxopt

I am working with cvxopt matrices in order to use them in picos library. In general I want to take a matrix, evaluate it on a certain vector, subtract something, then take the biggest absolute value of its entries

```
import picos as pic
import cvxopt as cvx
import numpy as np

(...)

P = pic.Problem()
theta = P.add_variable('theta', size=k, vtype='continuous', lower=-10, upper=10)
theta

P.add_constraint(max(abs(M*theta - b)) <= 5)
P.minimize(theta)
```

(Here b is some vector treated as cvxopt matrix.) However, the error I get is the following:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-8884e5cb14dc> in <module>
      3 theta
      4 
----> 5 P.add_constraint(max(abs(M*theta - b.T)) < 45)
      6 P.minimize(theta)
      7 

TypeError: 'Norm' object is not iterable
```

I was wondering if there is an alternative way of making these computations that would be acceptable to cvxopt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Never really used this lib apart from smaller experiments years ago)

This looks like the culprit is the classic case of hidden-magic in those highly-complex automatic-transformation modelling system tools.

- picos **overloads** `abs` in `abs(M*theta - b)`

  - see: [doc](https://picos-api.gitlab.io/picos/tutorial.html#norm-of-an-affine-expression)
  - this results in type `Norm` (a picos-based type)
- picos *probably* does not overload `max` in `max(abs(M*theta - b.T))`

  - python's max-operator (not something customized from picos!) will be used which is based on linear-search on some iterable
  - the iterable here would be the `Norm` object; but it's not iterable as the error shows

See also: [list of overloaded operators](https://picos-api.gitlab.io/picos/api/expressions.html#module-picos.expressions)

It seems to me, this feature `max` is missing. You can linearize it manually, but well... that's annoying.

If you don't need something special of picos, [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/index.html) is very similar and also  supports `abs` and `max` (and is based on scipy's sparse-matrices + numpy-arrays; thank god!).

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt a late clarification in case other users stumble upon this question.

As @sascha pointed out, PICOS uses the Python builtin function `abs` to denote a norm as opposed to an entry-wise absolute value. More precisely, `abs` denotes the absolute value of a real scalar, the modulus of a complex scalar, the Euclidean norm of a vector, and the Frobenius norm of a matrix. (Other norms are implemented in the `Norm`, `NuclearNorm`, and `SpectralNorm` classes.)

There are two options to pose an upper bound $b$ on the maximum entry-wise absolute value of a matrix expression $A$. The first is to use the $L_{p,q}$-norm for $p = q = \infty$:

```py
P += Norm(A, float("inf")) <= b
```

The second option is to give the bound via two linear inequalities:

```
P += A <= b, -A <= b
```

This works as $b$ is broadcasted to the shape of $A$ and this is also what the solver will see with the first option.