# TypeError in CVXPY: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Inequality'

Tags: python, numpy, cvxpy

Still playing with CVXPY. This time I get an interesting error. Let us look at this minimal code

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

A = np.random.normal(0, 1, (64,6))
b = np.random.normal(0, 1, (64,1))
theta = cp.Variable(shape = (6,1))

prob = cp.Problem(
    cp.Minimize(cp.max(A*theta -b) <= 5),
    [-10 <= theta, theta <= 10])
```

Once compiled, I get the following error:

> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\constants\constant.py in **init**(self, value)
>        42             self._sparse = True
>        43         else:
>   ---> 44             self._value = intf.DEFAULT_INTF.const_to_matrix(value)
>        45             self._sparse = False
>        46         self._imag = None
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\interface\numpy_interface\ndarray_interface.py in const_to_matrix(self, value, convert_scalars)
>        48             return result
>        49         else:
>   ---> 50             return result.astype(numpy.float64)
>        51 
>        52     # Return an identity matrix.
>
> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Inequality'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want to model exactly, but here something which works:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

A = np.random.normal(0, 1, (64,6))
b = np.random.normal(0, 1, (64,1))
theta = cp.Variable(shape = (6,1))

prob = cp.Problem(
            cp.Minimize(cp.sum(theta)),  # what do you want to minimize?
            [
                cp.max(A*theta -b) <= 5,
                -10 <= theta,
                theta <= 10
            ]
        )
```

works and should show the problem.

I would prefer a more clean impl like:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

A = np.random.normal(0, 1, (64,6))
b = np.random.normal(0, 1, (64,1))
theta = cp.Variable(shape = (6,1))

obj = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(theta))          # what do you want to minimize?
                                          # feasibility-problem? -> use hardcoded constant: cp.Minimize(0)
constraints = [
    cp.max(A*theta -b) <= 5,
    -10 <= theta,
    theta <= 10
]

prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
```

The reason: it's easier to read out what's happening exactly.

**Your problem:** your objective has a constraint, which is impossible.

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

A = np.random.normal(0, 1, (64,6))
b = np.random.normal(0, 1, (64,1))
theta = cp.Variable(shape = (6,1))

prob = cp.Problem(
cp.Minimize(cp.max(A*theta -b) <= 5),  # first argument = objective
                                       # -> minimize (constraint) : impossible!
    [-10 <= theta, theta <= 10])       # second argument = constraints
                                       # -> box-constraints
```

Shortly speaking:

- you *want* to minimize a function
- you *do* minimize an inequality

## Towards comment below:

*edit*

```
obj = cp.Minimize(cp.max(cp.abs(A*theta-b)))
```

Small check:

```
print((A*theta-b).shape)
(64, 1)
print((cp.abs(A*theta-b)).shape)
(64, 1)
```

Elementwise abs: good

The final outer `max` results in a single value, or else `cp.Minimize` won't accept it. good

**EDIT** Or let's make cvxpy and us more happy:

```
obj = cp.Minimize(cp.norm(A*theta-b, "inf"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I want to minimise the maxima of absolute values of the vector $A\theta - b$.

Comment: I want to minimise the Chebyshev norm of the vector.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance

Comment: (**dumb comment :-D** please ignore) I have to admit, that i'm approaching some limit here as i'm not that familiar with this norm. `minimise the maxima of absolute values of the vector` is for me exactly `min l1-norm(vector)`. Or not?

Comment: This is the l_infty-norm (the l1 is the sum of absolute values).

Comment: Argh, yeah, sry. Let me think about yours for a sec.